# How to understand scheme://host.domain:port/path/filename?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, subdomain

I'm learning HTML at `www.w3schools.com/html/html_urlencode.asp` and don't understand this sentence:

> host - defines the domain host (default host for http is www)

Example

*scheme://host.domain:port/path/filename*

Explanation:

```
    scheme - defines the type of Internet service (most common is http)
    host - defines the domain host (default host for http is www)
    domain - defines the Internet domain name (w3schools.com)
    port - defines the port number at the host (default for http is 80)
    path - defines a path at the server (If omitted: the root directory of the site)
    filename - defines the name of a document or resource
```

What is the relation between "domain host" and "www"?

Comment: Opinion: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use.

Comment: why not reliable? their tutorials are free, and easy to follow.

Comment: how do you make this conclusion?

Comment: Click on the link in my comment

Comment: I get your point now, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_urlencode.asp
```

The domain = `w3schools.com`

www is the host.
The path is `/html/` 
And the file is `html_urlencode.asp`

Comment: Actually `www` is the hostname, `w3schools.com` is the domain. Hostname is a single word inside a (sub)domain.

Comment: You're so very right.